# PHP Dbus stable implementation

Tags: php, dbus

My situation:
    I have a software composed of some compiled C++ daemons running in the background, a PHP/JS web interface and a CLI interface written in Python. Currently to send a Dbus command from PHP (web interface) to a daemon we use a python script to proxy the call, because python has a very mature Dbus implementation.

My Question:
There is any stable Dbus implementations to use withing PHP, compatible with Ubuntu Server/CentOs ?

What have I tried:
 - The beta [DBUS plugin in PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/DBus) that is not documented, still in beta, and complains about missing X11 envion (how is this good for servers ?).
 - And then there is the [GREE php-dbus](https://github.com/gree/php-dbus) extension that is not maintained, link to documentations redirects to a Japanese blog.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, PHP executed under Apache **can do** D-Bus requests!

The thing is that the D-Bus requests are limited to a single user, in the way that, say the www-data user can do request to processes owned by www-data, but not to other users.

This limitation is by-design, and probally also due to security: there will be no D-bus inter-user communication!

You can start a D-Bus server for the user www-data like

```
> sudo -u www-data sh -c "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/tmp/dbus-www-data &&  dbus-daemon --fork --session --print-address 1 --address='unix:path=/tmp/dbus-www-data'"
```

or similar. If it works you should then see a pipe in /tmp like

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    0 Aug  1 09:15 dbus-www-data=
```

Since www-data cannot login directly (no sudo www-data), you need to execute in a shell command (-c), export the D-Bus session address (session socket/data located in /tmp/dbus-www-data, that during the call will be created), and then launch the dbus daemon with this D-bus address.

This works in my Apache2/PHP/C++ setup, but is rather complicated to debug due to the use of the www-data user.

Answer (score 1):

PHP executed on a web server (like Apache) can't do D-Bus requests at all. I'm trying for several days without success. This is because the web server user (like `www-data`) can't access the `dbus-daemon` via a `session` connexion.

As a workaround I'm using the [React](http://reactphp.org/) built-in [HTTP server](https://github.com/reactphp/http). Exactly like you, but all in PHP. Your workaround is much more reliable.